# How Web API Return Nested JSON Values by HttpPost call from database?

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api

I dont have any problems but i don't know how API call data Nested Values

My Web API have Controller, Models and DataAccess that i call by use sql to call data

I want API call JSON Data format similar as below :

```
[
      {
        "Agent_Code": "123456",
        "Name": "Miss Sara Manger",
        "NickName": "Sara",
        "BirthDay": "19690825",
        "CardID": "9999999999",
        "Address": "870  Goldleaf Lane Lyndhurst NJ New Jersey 07071",
        "Mobile": "000000000",
        "Email": "utv9hgn3h0k@classesmail.com",
        "Bank": [
                      {
                        "AcctName": "Miss Sara Manger",
                        "Acctno": "9999999999",
                        "Bank": "KBANK"
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Testdata.APIs
{
    public class DashController : BaseApiController

    {
    [HttpPost]
       public List<Models.AgentDto> TestJSON(Models.CountDashReq model)
            {

                DataAccess.DashDAL dal = new DataAccess.DashDAL();
                List<Models.AgentDto> models = dal.TestJSON(model);

                return models;
            }
}
```

Model AgentDto And BankDto:

```
public class AgentDto
    {
        public string Agent_Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string NickName { get; set; }
        public string BirthDay { get; set; }
        public string CardID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Bank { get; set; }
    }

    public class BankDto
    {
        public string AcctName { get; set; }
        public string Acctno { get; set; }
        public string Bank { get; set; }
    }
```

DataAccess:

```
    public List<Models.AgentDto> TestJSON(Models.CountDashReq model)
    {
        string sql = "[dbo].[tb_Json_Get]";
        List<Models.AgentDto> result = new List<Models.AgentDto>();

        if (model != null)
        {

            List<SqlParameter> reqParam = new List<SqlParameter>();

            //reqParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@usrLogin", model.usrLogin));

            DataSet ds = this.Execute(sql, CommandType.StoredProcedure, reqParam.ToArray(), false);

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Models.AgentDto paramslist = DataAccessUtility.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable<Models.AgentDto>(row);

                    result.Add(paramslist);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Please help me to use Case-when Thank you very much

Comment: Use a library like Jackson, to help you serialize/deserialize from and to json. There are some tutorials online on Jackson.
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you getting request JSON as:

```
[
  {
    "Agent_Code": "123456",
    "Name": "Miss Sara Manger",
    "NickName": "Sara",
    "BirthDay": "19690825",
    "CardID": "9999999999",
    "Address": "870  Goldleaf Lane Lyndhurst NJ New Jersey 07071",
    "Mobile": "000000000",
    "Email": "utv9hgn3h0k@classesmail.com",
    "Bank": [
      {
        "AcctName": "Miss Sara Manger",
        "Acctno": "9999999999",
        "Bank": "KBANK"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then the `CountDashReq` class should be:

```
public class Bank
{
    public string AcctName { get; set; }
    public string Acctno { get; set; }
    public string Bank { get; set; }
}

public class CountDashReq
{
    public string Agent_Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string BirthDay { get; set; }
    public string CardID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Bank> Bank { get; set; }
}
```

In controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Models.AgentDto> TestJSON(IList<Models.CountDashReq> model)
{
  // Your code
}
```